# How does length of vector u+v squared equal (u+v) * (u+v)

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, vectors

[image]

For the proof of **Theorem Of Pythagoras** the above is given.
Can anyone explain how the first step is derived? How is the length of vector **u** and vector **v** squared produce the following on the right hand side?

Comment: That's just $||w||^2 = w \cdot w\,$ with $w=u+v\,$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot product of two vectors is given by $$ v\cdot w = |v||w|\cos(\theta) $$ where $\theta$ is the angle between them and $|v|$ means length of $v$. When the two vectors are the same, the angle is $0$, so the formula reduces to $$ v\cdot v = |v|^2.$$

Another (equivalent) formula for the dot product is in terms of components: $$ v\cdot w = v_1w_1+v_2w_2+\ldots +v_nw_n $$

Again, when we go to the case where $v = w,$ it reduces to $$ v\cdot v = v_1^2 + v_2^2 + \ldots +v_n^2 = |v|^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

That is true by definition of the Euclidean norm.

$$\|x\| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + ...+x_n^2}=\sqrt{x.x}$$

Comment: There are some exponents missing.

Comment: Oops. Thank you for pointing that out. Corrected.

Comment: Sure. Minor latex comment: I would use \cdot to make the dot when writing $x \cdot x$.